# CMap::mergeArray in Yii

Tags: php, arrays, yii

I know CMap::mergeArray in Yii merges two array. But I have three array and I want to make them merge through CMap::mergeArray. So how to merge all the three array in Yii framework.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It depends on what you want. The key difference to note is that CMap will overwrite existing keys, which is different from the built in php functions:

> If each array has an element with the same string key value, the
>   latter will overwrite the former (different from
>   array_merge_recursive)

If you do CMap::mergeWith as above, you'll just be getting a new array consisting of the 3 arrays as subelements:

For example, given the following structure:

```
$foo = array (
    'a' => 1,
    'b' => 2,
    'c' => 3,
    'z' => 'does not exist in other arrays',
    );

$bar = array (
    'a' => 'one',
    'b' => 'two', 
    'c' => 'three',
);

$arr = array (
    'a' => 'uno',
    'b' => 'dos',
    'c' => 'tres',
);
```

Using CMap::mergeWith as follows:

```
$map = new CMap();
$map->mergeWith (array($foo, $bar, $arr));
print_r($map);
```

Results in the following:

```
CMap Object
(
    [_d:CMap:private] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [a] => 1
                    [b] => 2
                    [c] => 3
                    [z] => does not exist in other arrays
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [a] => one
                    [b] => two
                    [c] => three
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [a] => uno
                    [b] => dos
                    [c] => tres
                )

        )

    [_r:CMap:private] => 
    [_e:CComponent:private] => 
    [_m:CComponent:private] => 
)
```

If overwriting elements is the preferred behavior, then the following will work:

```
$map = new CMap ($foo);
$map->mergeWith ($bar);
$map->mergeWith ($arr);
print_r($map);
```

Which results in:

```
CMap Object
(
    [_d:CMap:private] => Array
        (
            [a] => uno
            [b] => dos
            [c] => tres
            [z] => does not exist in other arrays
        )

    [_r:CMap:private] => 
    [_e:CComponent:private] => 
    [_m:CComponent:private] => 
)
```

If, however, you want the data appended, then:

```
$map = new CMap (array_merge_recursive ($foo, $bar, $arr));
print_r($map);
```

Will get you there:

```
CMap Object
(
    [_d:CMap:private] => Array
        (
            [a] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                    [1] => one
                    [2] => uno
                )

            [b] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2
                    [1] => two
                    [2] => dos
                )

            [c] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 3
                    [1] => three
                    [2] => tres
                )

            [z] => does not exist in other arrays
        )

    [_r:CMap:private] => 
    [_e:CComponent:private] => 
    [_m:CComponent:private] => 
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`array_merge`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)`($ar1, $ar2, $ar3)` OR [`array_merge_recursive`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php)`($ar1, $ar2, $ar3)`

Also you could use:

```
CMap::mergeWith(array($ar1, $ar2, $ar3));
```

But I am not sure for the result of the former

Comment: Yii is just a PHP framework so all core PHP functions will work in Yii. But if you try to merge CMap objects and not PHP arrays using array_merge/array_merge_recursive you'll get an error.